# paint(graphics)) not working with GraphPinScene

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, scene

I want to an image on my scene, so I used this:

```
BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) SemapGraphResources.ssTerresteImage;
Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
scene.paint(g2);
scene.validate();
```

But I got that error:

**Stacktrace**:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Scene.validate was not called after last change. Widget is not validated. See first Q/A at http://graph.netbeans.org/faq.html page.
    at org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Widget.paint(Widget.java:1402)
    at org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Widget.paintChildren(Widget.java:1481)
    at org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Widget.paint(Widget.java:1427)
at org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Scene.paint(Scene.java:251)
```

Comment: Try calling scene.validate() first and then scene.paint(g2).

Comment: I did it but in vain : (